# how to store data from vb.net to access a database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am using an Access database and vb.net 2010. I have created a table in the database with columns for title, datein, dateout and roomnymber.  In vb.net 2010 I made a distinguished title = combobox, datein and dateout = DateTimePicker.  When I click on F5, an error occurs: INSERT INTO Syntax Error in statement. Here's my code:

```
Dim sql As String
  sql = "INSERT INTO tcekin(title,firstname,lastname,address,country,company,roomnumber,datein,dateout,rommtype,note)" & "VALUES('" & ComboBox1.Text & _
  "','" & txtFirstName.Text & "','" & txtLastName.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "','" & cboCountry.Text & "','" & txtCompany.Text & "','" & txtNumber.Text & _
  "','" & dptDateIn.Text & "','" & dptDateOut.Text & "','" & cboRoom.Text & "','" & txtNotes.Text & "')"
  cmmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
```

Comment: English only, please.  I will provide a google translation in a moment and might even edit for content by hand, but you're likely to do much better by editing the question to ask in English in your own words.

Comment: owgh..Im sory, because my English Broken ^^

Answer (score 3):

The first problem here is never NEVER **NEVER** use string concatenation to build your queries like that.  Do it like this instead:

```
Dim sql As String = _
    "INSERT INTO tcekin " &_
    "(title,firstname,lastname,address,country,company,roomnumber,datein,dateout,rommtype,note)" &_
    "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
cmmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, cnn)
cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", Combobox1.Text)
cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text)
''# ...
''# ...
```

This will also make it easier to spot and avoid syntax errors like the one you're complaining about.

Comment: so I must add cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", txtFirstName.Text)
 one by one ? from txtFirstName until note ?

Comment: Yes.  Always use parameterized queries.  The string concatenation method you were using causes you query to be vulnerable to sql injection hacks.